# Add multiple language record in oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Hi I have created a table `Continent` using below query

```
CREATE TABLE CONTINENTS
(
  CONTNTCOD        NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
  LOOKUPCOD        VARCHAR2(20),
  CONTNAM          VARCHAR2(50),
  CONTNAM_LCLLANG  VARCHAR2(50),

);
```

The fourth column i.e. `CONTNAM_LCLLANG` is used to store data in different language.

When i tried to insert 
`अभिषेक` it inserted something `¿¿¿¿¿¿`

Comment: Well, you can't store random Unicode characters in a `VARCHAR2` column unless you change the encoding of the entire database server (and your edition supports it). Why don't you switch to `NVARCHAR2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Unicode like utf8 or utf8_general_ci( in mysql ) because it support a many characters.

so, what you can do is change **varchar** to **nvarchar**

CREATE TABLE CONTINENTS
(

```
  CONTNTCOD        NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,

  LOOKUPCOD        VARCHAR2(20),

  CONTNAM          VARCHAR2(50),

  CONTNAM_LCLLANG  NVARCHAR2(50),
```

);

Comment: Or create your database with the AL32UTF8 character set.

Comment: Please note that `utf8_general_ci` is a **MySQL** collation. It has nothing to do with Oracle, where the equivalent string looks like what BobC has shared.